# Any way to get the file path to the source file of an embedded resource at runtime?

Tags: embedded-resource, pdb-files

I am working on a VirtualPathProvider which will let me load embedded resources (ER) (such as .js or .css files) from a referenced assembly. I would like to be able to change the .js files and .css files at runtime and have the changes reflected without having to refresh the whole page. I can do this if I have the path to the resource file as I can use that as the source instead of the ER.

Is there any way to extract the source code location of an assemblies csproj or an embedded resource at runtime, perhaps from the .pdb file, and if so, how would I do it in c#? Thanks!